# How to upload a csv file multiple times on Safari using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, safari

I have written a web app where I want to upload a `CSV` file. It is working as intended on Chrome, but it does not work on Safari.

Below is the Angularjs code to upload file,

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (file) {
    var name, extension, browser;
    var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (isSafari) {
        name = file.fileName;
        extension = name.split('.')[name.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();

        if (extension != "csv") {
            alert("Selected File is not a valid .CSV file. Please select a .CSV file.");
            return false;
        }
    }

//Code to save file to server

}
```

Below is the HTML code to call the above function,

```
<input id="uploader" type="file" ngf-select="uploadFile(uploadedFile)" 
ng-model="uploadedFile" ngf-max-size="100MB" name="file" 
ngf-accept="'application/csv, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, *.csv, .csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.ms-excel'">
```

When I click the `input` button the first time, the function gets called correctly. The selected file gets uploaded as expected. The issue begins when I try to upload the same file the second time. The `uploadFile` function gets called as soon as I click the `<input >` file picker.

The above problem described occurs only in Safari, and not in Chrome.

How do I modify my code such a way that every time I click to upload a file, the function gets called only after I select the file?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this problem?

Comment: No. Still searching for the answer.

Comment: I managed to solve this by putting accept=".csv,text/csv".

Comment: Cool. Thanks for letting me know!